# WordPress Buddypress User roles and capabilities and Protected contents for specific user levels

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, buddypress, user-roles

I am trying to set specific role/permissions for users in BuddyPress using plugin 'role manager' (http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/role-manager/) but some how it's not working as it should be. Here is my settings in WP dashboard:

[image]

Am I setting the wrong user level?

Also, how can I setup password protected contents for specific user roles?

The only thing I have tried so far is 'role manager' settings in WP dashboard (as shown in above image)

Any suggestions / help will be appreciated.

~ Dipak G.

Comment: Please try this **[link](http://shinephp.com/user-role-editor-wordpress-plugin/)**

Comment: @Prashant I am going to look into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress currently doesn't make use of WordPress roles and capabilities. What does this mean? You can set/edit capabilities for certain roles, like in your screenshot above, and it'll only affect that user trying to access default WordPress content or admin features.

It won't have any impact at all on BuddyPress, or any of its features.